# Custom Flat Progress Bar

Tags: wpf, xaml, progress-bar

I'm trying to create a progress bar similar to what looks like below, it's in an Indeterminate effect so it'll just be an animation looping over and over.

[image]

The problem I'm having is where do I begin?

My main logic on this would be that i need to overlay a rectangle on top of another and then apply some sort of animation to make the top rectangle move and then just loop that same thing.

I can do this in a storyboard in Blend but I don't think this is the best way to achieve this.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

EDIT:

**Working XAML:**

```
    <Style x:Key="{x:Type ProgressBar}"
       TargetType="{x:Type ProgressBar}">
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ProgressBar}">
        <Grid MinHeight="14"
              MinWidth="200"
              Background="#FFF0F0F0">
          <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
              <VisualState x:Name="Determinate" />
              <VisualState x:Name="Indeterminate">
                <Storyboard>
                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="00:00:00"
                                                 Storyboard.TargetName="PART_Indicator"
                                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00">
                      <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        <SolidColorBrush>#FFF0F0F0</SolidColorBrush>
                      </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                </Storyboard>
              </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
          </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
          <Border x:Name="PART_Track"
                  CornerRadius="0"
                  BorderThickness="1">
            <Border.BorderBrush>
              <SolidColorBrush Color="#FFF0F0F0" />
            </Border.BorderBrush>
          </Border>
          <Border x:Name="PART_Indicator"
                  CornerRadius="0"
                  BorderThickness="0"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                  Background="#FF4B8BC2"
                  Margin="0,-1,0,1">
            <Border.BorderBrush>
              <SolidColorBrush Color="#FFD7D7D7" />

            </Border.BorderBrush>
            <Grid ClipToBounds="True"
                  x:Name="Animation">
              <Border x:Name="PART_GlowRect"
                         Width="100"
                         HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                         Background="#FF4B8BC2"
                         Margin="-100,0,0,0" />
            </Grid>
          </Border>
        </Grid>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
  <Setter Property="Background">
    <Setter.Value>
      <SolidColorBrush Color="#FFF0F0F0" />
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
  <Setter Property="Foreground">
    <Setter.Value>
      <SolidColorBrush Color="#FF4B8BC2" />
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: So what seems to be an issue? You already have a template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should start by reading about [ProgressBar Styles and Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750638.aspx). `ProgressBar` has some named parts like `PART_Indicator` or `PART_Track`. They are identified by name in order to be used in correct places. It also has 2 `CommonStates`: `Determinate` for when you want to show real progress and `Indeterminate` for when you want to show a progress. You don't have to worry about overlays. If you name parts of the template correctly it will be done automatically for you.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to that link, I've updated my question with code I've tried and the result. Although it's quite not there, have you any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The faded looking gradients on the ends, is that a cause of the visualstate?

Comment: In your template replace `PART_GlowRect` `Rectagle` with `Border`, `Fill` with `Background` and set it to blue you want. Should help